# Pyinstaller guidance

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I tried pyinstaller after reading few tutorials (in a hurry, though) and watching some video tuts. It beautifully made the dist folder which contains the executable file which runs on my ubuntu.
But when copied the same folder on windows 8 system, windows simply doesn't recognize it.

What I want is to make one single file for ubuntu, 1 for windows and 1 for mac such that users click on it and then a few nexts and then it gets installed on the system. A desktop icon should be created for it, just like normal softwares.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't "cross-bundle" with Pyinstaller.

If you want to distribute your application on multiple operating systems, you must install pyinstaller and bundle your app separately on each, as explained on [this page](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#supporting-multiple-operating-systems)

Comment: I got it but I am a bit curious about  how single click and install softwares are made...Any reference to that would be quite helpful